# Using slice() as an alternative to []

Tags: r, dplyr

As far as I understand, `slice()` should be equivalent to selecting rows by number inside the square brackets. Could someone please explain to me why I get two different results in the following code?

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

flights %>% group_by(dest) %>% count(sort = TRUE) -> top_dest

top_dest[1:20,]

top_dest %>% slice(1:20)
```

Moreover, I would like to know what I should use that can replace the square brackets and be combined with the pipe function (so that I would not need two command lines, but one).

Comment: slice doesn't maintain any row orders. So can really compare the two. BTW, we can begin our dplyr formatted code using top_dest[1:20,] as the result is also a tibble.

Comment: Ok. So, basically there is no way to replace 'top_dest[1:20,]' with something that can be a step in the pipe flow and I have to break the flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get different results is because your data is grouped. So `slice` is selecting 20 rows for each `dest`. There is no impact of grouping on `top_dest[1:20,]`. You can `ungroup` the dataframe and then select 20 rows to get the same result.

```
library(dplyr)
top_dest %>% ungroup %>% slice(1:20)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to do! In this way, I can write down a unique command line. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
top_dest %>%
    ungroup %>%
    filter(row_number() < 21)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is ```filter(row_number() < 21) ``` exactly the same as ```slice(1:20)```?

Comment: @user12703198 yes, it returns the first 20 rows